# Use decorators to manipulate object properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection, ecmascript-6, decorator

Let's say I have two objects, a car and a list of persons. Inside my car object I have a list of ID's representing passengers. I would like to create a decorator I can put on the list (ie. `@personIDs public passengers: person[];`) so that, once the list is created I can replace the ID's with references to the actual object.

ex.

```
function personIDs(target: any, key: string) {
    for(let id of target) id = persons.filter((p) => {return p.id == id;})[0];
}
```

My problem is that, as far as I can tell, I can only access the meta-data and not the actual values. Is there a work around or a simple elegant solution to this?

Comment: did you want to specify some IDs when you call the decorator . OR all IDs ? I mean you will use it as `@personIDs([1, 4, 5])` OR `@personIDs` without args ?

Comment: I envision that the property it's self will hold the ID's so we dont need to specify them.

Comment: great ..so autowired by attribute (prop) name . alright!